# Explain FOR in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am making a test. I have all tests in rows, so my rows looks like this;

```
ID  |  TEST
----------------------------------
1   |  'select sysdate from dual'
2   |  'select sysdatesss from dual'
```

Now I read it row by row and I need to test it with `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR`

so the for the first row it would be

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR select sysdate from dual
```

but I have problem converting the `TEST` field. Right now I use;

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR testing.TEST
```

but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A SQL statement is a string, but you have to use dynamic SQL to convert a SQL statement that is stored as a string.

```
FOR i IN (SELECT t.test
            FROM TESTING t) LOOP
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'EXPLAIN PLAN FOR '|| i.test ||'';
END LOOP;
```

Reference:

- [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/2109681/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-option-for-Dynamic-SQL-and-PLSQL.htm)

Answer (score 2):

EXEC IMMEDIATE 'EXPLAIN PLAN FOR ' ||  TESTING.TEST