# oracle EXPLAIN PLAN

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, database-performance, query-performance

I am trying to run EXPLAIN PLAN for a dynamically created sql query.
Is this possible and how?

My code:

```
declare  
  l_sql varchar2(100);
begin
  l_sql:= 'select *from my_employees';
  EXPLAIN PLAN for l_sql; 
  commit;
end;
```

The error that I get is :
PLS-00103:Encountered the symbol "PLAN" when expecting on of the following: :=.(@%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944250/explain-for-in-oracle)

So the code should be like this:

```
 declare  
   l_sql varchar2(100);
 begin
   l_sql:= 'EXPLAIN PLAN for select *from my_employees';
   execute immediate l_sql;
   commit;
  end;
```